# Switching off register variables in Microsoft vc++ 1.52

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 1.52 to compile some MS-DOS code.
I know that in Borland CPP 3.1 there's a compiler optimization option in the IDE to switch off register variables.

But where's this option in the IDE of Visual C++ 1.52, if there's anyone familiar with it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What is the problem that's supposed to solve? Considering the age of that Visual C++ version, it would only know about base 32-bit x86 targets, which were register-poor so barely used registers for arguments or variables unless specified with the (now obsolete) `register` keyword. And even then the compiler most likely disregarded it.

Comment: I just downloaded the `ISO` to check what options it has. [summary](https://pastebin.com/vVmUGCDu) - Register allocation seems disabled by default. "`/Od` _disable optimization (default)_" and "`/Oe` _enable registers allocation_" seems to imply that anyway.